# How many differences does it need in this correlogram of the unstationary data

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I added different kinds of differencing plot and I tried many models based on these. These monthly datas are the incidence rate of the disease. But still can’t find out the appropriate seasonal arima model. Does anybody has ideas on the model (p d q) (P D Q)12 identification? Would you recommand the possible model?

I am doing the SARIMA modelling and I am a beginner in this field. I have no idea how to estimates the differences in this picture.
Please help me to resolve the problem[image]

Comment: Cool table/plot. What software did you use?

Comment: Eviews software^^

Answer (score 0):

possibly 1 regular differencing and 1 seasonal ar 12 OR 2 differences ... 1 and 12 ... ONLY YOUR DATA KNOWS FOR SURE as there could be seasonal pulses involved and not seasonal arima – IrishStat 1 min ago     Edit

If you post your data I will try and help further. The acf and the pacf ARE OFTEN AMBIGUOUS .... particularly when you have deterministic structure in your data i.e. 
pulses , level shifts , seasonal pulses , local time trends OR non-constant error variance or non-constant model parameters over time

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. But I can’t still find the suitable model. Would you recommand the possible model based on these plots?